# How is `open()` with `O_EXEC` different and related to `execve()`?

Tags: c, linux, file, exec

From APUE, `open()` has a flag option

> O_EXEC Open for execute only.

However, I only see `execve()` is used in the examples that I have seen.

So when is `open()` with `O_EXEC` used? How is that different and related to `execve()`?

Comment: On which system did you see an `O_EXEC` flag defined for `open()`?  I just checked several, and I'm not seeing it.  I agree it's a strange-sounding flag.  I'm guessing you saw it on sone system that had an experimental, non-standard `exec` variant, that allowed executing a program from an open file descriptor rather than its path (as of course the ordinary `exec` variants all do).

Comment: It is a GNU/Hurd quirk, only available on GNU/Hurd systems. See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Access-Modes).

Comment: @SteveSummit how did you search for it in your systems? I don't know how to search, and took the information  from APUE.

Comment: @Tim: It is specified in [POSIX.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) too, but I *believe* GNU/Hurd is the only current system that supports it. Nix that; some BSD's have it too. (It also seems to be included in newlib (for embedded Linux systems) as an alias for O_SEARCH.)

Comment: @Tim I just typed `man 2 open` on each system.  Also I checked https://linux.die.net/man/2/open, which is a great reference.

Comment: Since this is tagged [tag:linux], it is important to point out that `O_EXEC` does not work in Linux at all. [`fexecve()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fexecve.3.html) takes a file descriptor, that must refer to a file opened with `O_RDONLY` or `O_PATH`.

Comment: @SteveSummit: The [Linux man pages project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/) is better maintained (as it is the upstream of all man pages in all linux distros), and yes, APUE is [Advanced Programming in Unix Environment](http://apuebook.com/) by Rich Stevens.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thanks for that link.  Fascinating.  Anyone interested in this stuff should read the NOTES section in the [linked man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fexecve.3.html).  Checksumming a file before executing it is an interesting and important application which I never would have thought of.

Comment: I could write an answer that delves into executing files via a file descriptor, if that would be useful? As it stands right now, there is little to answer to the stated question, as the related function is `fexecve()`, not `execve()`.

Comment: (@SteveSummit: Another use case is to avoid bait-and-switch race conditions when a privileged program executes a helper binary to do some sensitive task. Information can be securely provided via a pipe between the two. However, if the containing directory is not (or cannot be) secured for operational reasons, a nefarious user can try an attack where a binary is replaced with another between an ownership/mode check and execution. The real binary is usually a hard link to an immutable binary on same fs but outside the chroot used.)